# "How to make CUPS work on an IPv4 secured network?": which group suits this question?

Tags: discussion

I submitted this question on `Ask Different` but it is also clearly a network engineering question (my tool is `tcpdump` here :) ):

[How to make shared printing works on an IPv4 only network?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/188399/22003)

Do you have any idea on how to solve this problem?

Do you think this question would get a better answer in `Network Engineering`?

---

My problem stands at the frontier between network engineering, system
engineering (Unix & MacOS X oriented). So my hidden question was:
on which group will it be the most efficient to submit this question so as
to avoid repetting questions and dissiminated answers?

Comment: To the authors of these down votes:↵
do you mean that this question is irrelevant here or that you don't understand my question and I should improve its wording?

Comment: Unfortunately, home networking is off-topic here.  You can ask on Superuser.

Comment: My example is small to help everyone understand it :). But I'm not dealing with a home network problem here.

Comment: You could try asking on Superuser.

Comment: If you're not asking about home networking, don't use home networking as an example.  Otherwise I would say that if it doesn't involve configuration of a switch, router, WLC/AP, firewall, network-related server (DHCP/syslog/etc.) or load-balancer (but DNS is apparently bad...) it should be on a different SE site.  If there is a CUPS proxy on a WLC, it could be relevant here but it doesn't seem to be. Since it is directly Apple's application related, Ask Different is probably your best bet.

Comment: Thank you for reading my question :).
Is it the Internet side @IP I gave to Bob which lead you to think "home network"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is not a good fit for NE. Like many other questions of this type, while the network is used for the application the questions really isn't about the network.

This question is purely centered on the application and operating system. Nothing changes on the network or needs to change on the network, nor would it change if  you dropped the situation on a different network. It is all about configuration and operation of those non-network related topics.

Even if you get answers (and maybe a better answer) here, that won't make it on topic.